# Eclipse doesn't show src/main/resources in my maven project the way I see it elsewhere

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working on a maven project someone else created.  The package explorer in eclipse looks like

```
their_project_name
   src/main/java
   src/main/resources
   src/test/java
   src/test/resources
   JRE System Library
   Maven Dependencies
   ...
   src
      main
      test
   pom.xml
   their_project_name.launch
```

I'm also working on a Maven project I started from scratch.  Its structure looks like:

```
my_project_name
   src/main/java
   src/test/java
   JRE System Library
   Maven Dependencies
   src
      main
         resources
            ...
   pom.xml
```

In other words, when I tried to create the src/main/resources directory, it didn't show up in the explorer where I wanted it to go.  It instead went in this src folder, instead of showing up at the top level.  Is there a step I missed?  If I look at the workspace from my OS explorer, our directory structures are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

You need to add the resources folder to your classpath. Please do the following

1. Right click the folder
2. Hover over *Build Path*
3. Click *Use as Source Folder*

[image: eclipse]

> Those top level directories are source folder "short cuts"

Answer (score 2):

Did you create a `Folder` or a `Source Folder` ? The correct one is `Source Folder`, and with the correct name, it should show up next to the `src/main/java`.

Comment: That sounds right!  I'm "accepting" the answer for how to fix the incorrectly created folder in the first place, but this was definitely good for explaining how to avoid the problem in the first place later!

Comment: Solved my problem!! Right clicked the folder and browsed and added the existing `resources` folder. Swiftly it showed up!